# How can I add an additional temperature sensor (EZO RTD of Atlas Scientific) to an Atlas Scientific bare-bones wifi pool kit?

Tags: arduino-ide

### Problem summary

When I changed the I2C address of a sensor (EZO RTD) to another address (e.g., 50 or 100) from its default address (102), it didn't work on my Atlas Scientific bare-bones WiFi Hydroponics Kit.

### Specific description

I tried to add a temperature sensor (EZO RTD) to an Atlas Scientific bare-bones WiFi Hydroponics Kit that already has a pH Sensor (EZO pH) and a temperature sensor (EZO RTD) on the pH port and Temperature port, respectively. Since a provided setup guide of Atlas Scientific says that each sensor on the kit has to have a different I2C address when multiple sensors are used on it. So I assigned an I2C address "50" to the additional sensor and then added it to the AUX port (and tried the Temperature port as well), but it didn't work at all. Meanwhile, the temperature sensor with the default I2C address 102) works very well on both the Temperature and AUX ports. I guess this might be related to a coding problem. Atlas Scientific's provided code is as follows: THE CODE IS DELETED BY MYSELF

Thanks for reading my problem.

Jayjay

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

I solved this problem based on the answer I voted for.

The code I made is as follows:

```
#include <iot_cmd.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>                                         //include esp8266 wifi library 
#include "ThingSpeak.h"                                          //include thingspeak library
#include <sequencer4.h>                                          //imports a 4 function sequencer 
#include <sequencer1.h>                                          //imports a 1 function sequencer 
#include <Ezo_i2c_util.h>                                        //brings in common print statements
#include <Ezo_i2c.h> //include the EZO I2C library from https://github.com/Atlas-Scientific/Ezo_I2c_lib
#include <Wire.h>    //include arduinos i2c library

WiFiClient client;                                              //declare that this device connects to a Wi-Fi network,create a connection to a specified internet IP address

//----------------Fill in your Wi-Fi / ThingSpeak Credentials-------
const String ssid = "WIFI NAME";                                 //The name of the Wi-Fi network you are connecting to
const String pass = "WIFI PASSWORD";                             //Your WiFi network password
const long myChannelNumber = ;                            //Your Thingspeak channel number
const char * myWriteAPIKey = "";                 //Your ThingSpeak Write API Key
//------------------------------------------------------------------


Ezo_board PH = Ezo_board(99, "PH");       //create a PH circuit object, who's address is 99 and name is "PH"
Ezo_board EC = Ezo_board(100, "EC");      //create an EC circuit object who's address is 100 and name is "EC"
Ezo_board RTD = Ezo_board(102, "RTD");    //create an RTD circuit object who's address is 102 and name is "RTD"
Ezo_board RTD2 = Ezo_board(50, "RTD2");   //create an RTD circuit object who's address is 50 and name is "RTD2"
Ezo_board PMP = Ezo_board(103, "PMP");    //create an PMP circuit object who's address is 103 and name is "PMP"

Ezo_board device_list[] = {   //an array of boards used for sending commands to all or specific boards
  PH,
  EC,
  RTD,
  RTD2,
  PMP
};

Ezo_board* default_board = &device_list[0]; //used to store the board were talking to

//gets the length of the array automatically so we dont have to change the number every time we add new boards
const uint8_t device_list_len = sizeof(device_list) / sizeof(device_list[0]);

//enable pins for each circuit
const int EN_PH = 14;
const int EN_EC = 12;
const int EN_RTD = 15;
const int EN_AUX = 13;

const unsigned long reading_delay = 1000;                 //how long we wait to receive a response, in milliseconds 
const unsigned long thingspeak_delay = 15000;             //how long we wait to send values to thingspeak, in milliseconds

unsigned int poll_delay = 2000 - reading_delay * 2 - 300; //how long to wait between polls after accounting for the times it takes to send readings

//parameters for setting the pump output
#define PUMP_BOARD        PMP       //the pump that will do the output (if theres more than one)
#define PUMP_DOSE         -0.5      //the dose that the pump will dispense in  milliliters
#define EZO_BOARD         EC        //the circuit that will be the target of comparison
#define IS_GREATER_THAN   true      //true means the circuit's reading has to be greater than the comparison value, false mean it has to be less than
#define COMPARISON_VALUE  1000      //the threshold above or below which the pump is activated

float k_val = 0;                                          //holds the k value for determining what to print in the help menu

bool polling  = true;                                     //variable to determine whether or not were polling the circuits
bool send_to_thingspeak = true;                           //variable to determine whether or not were sending data to thingspeak

bool wifi_isconnected(){                            //function to check if wifi is connected
  return (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED);
}

void reconnect_wifi(){                                    //function to reconnect wifi if its not connected
  if(!wifi_isconnected()){
    WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    Serial.println("connecting to wifi");
  }
}

void thingspeak_send(){
  if (send_to_thingspeak == true) {                                                    //if we're datalogging
    if(wifi_isconnected()){
      int return_code = ThingSpeak.writeFields(myChannelNumber, myWriteAPIKey); 
      if (return_code == 200) {                                                          //code for successful transmission
          Serial.println("sent to thingspeak");
      }else{
        Serial.println("couldnt send to thingspeak");
      }
    }
  }
}

void step1();      //forward declarations of functions to use them in the sequencer before defining them
void step2();
void step3();
void step4();
Sequencer4 Seq(&step1, reading_delay,   //calls the steps in sequence with time in between them
               &step2, 300, 
               &step3, reading_delay,
               &step4, poll_delay);

Sequencer1 Wifi_Seq(&reconnect_wifi, 10000);  //calls the wifi reconnect function every 10 seconds

Sequencer1 Thingspeak_seq(&thingspeak_send, thingspeak_delay); //sends data to thingspeak with the time determined by thingspeak delay

void setup() {

  pinMode(EN_PH, OUTPUT);                                                         //set enable pins as outputs
  pinMode(EN_EC, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EN_RTD, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EN_AUX, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(EN_PH, LOW);                                                       //set enable pins to enable the circuits
  digitalWrite(EN_EC, LOW);
  digitalWrite(EN_RTD, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(EN_AUX, LOW);

  Wire.begin();                           //start the I2C
  Serial.begin(9600);                     //start the serial communication to the computer

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);                    //set ESP8266 mode as a station to be connected to wifi network
  ThingSpeak.begin(client);               //enable ThingSpeak connection
  Wifi_Seq.reset();                       //initialize the sequencers
  Seq.reset();
  Thingspeak_seq.reset();
}

void loop() {
 String cmd;                            //variable to hold commands we send to the kit

  Wifi_Seq.run();                        //run the sequncer to do the polling
  
  if (receive_command(cmd)) {            //if we sent the kit a command it gets put into the cmd variable
    polling = false;                     //we stop polling  
    send_to_thingspeak = false;          //and sending data to thingspeak
    if(!process_coms(cmd)){              //then we evaluate the cmd for kit specific commands
      process_command(cmd, device_list, device_list_len, default_board);    //then if its not kit specific, pass the cmd to the IOT command processing function
    }
  }
  
  if (polling == true) {                 //if polling is turned on, run the sequencer
    Seq.run();
    Thingspeak_seq.run();
  }
}
  
//function that controls the pumps activation and output
void pump_function(Ezo_board &pump, Ezo_board &sensor, float value, float dose, bool greater_than){
 if (sensor.get_error() == Ezo_board::SUCCESS) {                    //make sure we have a valid reading before we make any decisions
    bool comparison = false;                                        //variable for holding the reuslt of the comparison
    if(greater_than){                                               //we do different comparisons depending on what the user wants
      comparison = (sensor.get_last_received_reading() >= value);   //compare the reading of the circuit to the comparison value to determine whether we actiavte the pump
    }else{
      comparison = (sensor.get_last_received_reading() <= value);
    }
    if (comparison) {                                               //if the result of the comparison means we should activate the pump
      pump.send_cmd_with_num("d,", dose);                           //dispense the dose
      delay(100);                                                   //wait a few milliseconds before getting pump results
      Serial.print(pump.get_name());                                //get pump data to tell the user if the command was received successfully
      Serial.print(" ");
      char response[20]; 
      if(pump.receive_cmd(response, 20) == Ezo_board::SUCCESS){
        Serial.print("pump dispensed ");
      }else{
        Serial.print("pump error ");
      }
      Serial.println(response);
    }else {
      pump.send_cmd("x");                                          //if we're not supposed to dispense, stop the pump
    }
  }
}

void step1() {
  //send a read command. we use this command instead of RTD.send_cmd("R"); 
  //to let the library know to parse the reading
  RTD.send_read_cmd();
  RTD2.send_read_cmd();
}

void step2() {
  receive_and_print_reading(RTD);             //get the reading from the RTD circuit
    if ((RTD.get_error() == Ezo_board::SUCCESS) && (RTD.get_last_received_reading() > -1000.0)) { //if the temperature reading has been received and it is valid
    PH.send_cmd_with_num("T,", RTD.get_last_received_reading());
    EC.send_cmd_with_num("T,", RTD.get_last_received_reading());
    ThingSpeak.setField(2, String(RTD.get_last_received_reading(), 2));                 //assign temperature readings to the third column of thingspeak channel
  } else {                                                                                      //if the temperature reading is invalid
    PH.send_cmd_with_num("T,", 25.0);
    EC.send_cmd_with_num("T,", 25.0);                                                          //send default temp = 25 deg C to EC sensor
    ThingSpeak.setField(2, String(25.0, 2));                 //assign temperature readings to the third column of thingspeak channel
  }

  Serial.print(" ");
  receive_and_print_reading(RTD2);
  if ((RTD2.get_error() == Ezo_board::SUCCESS) && (RTD2.get_last_received_reading() > -1000.0)) { //if the temperature reading has been received and it is valid
    PH.send_cmd_with_num("T,", RTD2.get_last_received_reading());
    EC.send_cmd_with_num("T,", RTD2.get_last_received_reading());
    ThingSpeak.setField(3, String(RTD2.get_last_received_reading(), 2));                 //assign temperature readings to the third column of thingspeak channel
  } else {                                                                                      //if the temperature reading is invalid
    PH.send_cmd_with_num("T,", 25.0);
    EC.send_cmd_with_num("T,", 25.0);                                                          //send default temp = 25 deg C to EC sensor
    ThingSpeak.setField(3, String(25.0, 2));                 //assign temperature readings to the third column of thingspeak channel
  }

}


void step3() {
  //send a read command. we use this command instead of PH.send_cmd("R");
  //to let the library know to parse the reading
  PH.send_read_cmd();
  EC.send_read_cmd();
}

void step4() {
  receive_and_print_reading(PH);             //get the reading from the PH circuit
  if (PH.get_error() == Ezo_board::SUCCESS) {                                          //if the PH reading was successful (back in step 1)
     ThingSpeak.setField(1, String(PH.get_last_received_reading(), 2));                 //assign PH readings to the first column of thingspeak channel
  }
  Serial.print("  ");
  receive_and_print_reading(EC);             //get the reading from the EC circuit
  if (EC.get_error() == Ezo_board::SUCCESS) {                                          //if the EC reading was successful (back in step 1)
     ThingSpeak.setField(2, String(EC.get_last_received_reading(), 0));                 //assign EC readings to the second column of thingspeak channel
  }

  Serial.println();
  pump_function(PUMP_BOARD, EZO_BOARD, COMPARISON_VALUE, PUMP_DOSE, IS_GREATER_THAN);
}



void start_datalogging() {
  polling = true;                                                 //set poll to true to start the polling loop
  send_to_thingspeak = true;
  Thingspeak_seq.reset();
}

bool process_coms(const String &string_buffer) {      //function to process commands that manipulate global variables and are specifc to certain kits
  if (string_buffer == "HELP") {
    print_help();
    return true;
  }
  else if (string_buffer.startsWith("DATALOG")) {
     start_datalogging();
    return true;
  }
  else if (string_buffer.startsWith("POLL")) {
    polling = true;  
    Seq.reset();
    
    int16_t index = string_buffer.indexOf(',');                    //check if were passing a polling delay parameter
    if (index != -1) {                                              //if there is a polling delay
      float new_delay = string_buffer.substring(index + 1).toFloat(); //turn it into a float

      float mintime = reading_delay*2 + 300;
      if (new_delay >= (mintime/1000.0)) {                                       //make sure its greater than our minimum time
        Seq.set_step4_time((new_delay * 1000.0) - mintime);          //convert to milliseconds and remove the reading delay from our wait
      } else {
        Serial.println("delay too short");                          //print an error if the polling time isnt valid
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;                         //return false if the command is not in the list, so we can scan the other list or pass it to the circuit
}

void get_ec_k_value(){                                    //function to query the value of the ec circuit
  char rx_buf[10];                                        //buffer to hold the string we receive from the circuit
  EC.send_cmd("k,?");                                     //query the k value
  delay(300);
  if(EC.receive_cmd(rx_buf, 10) == Ezo_board::SUCCESS){   //if the reading is successful
    k_val = String(rx_buf).substring(3).toFloat();        //parse the reading into a float
  }
}

void print_help() {
  get_ec_k_value();
  Serial.println(F("Atlas Scientific I2C hydroponics kit                                       "));
  Serial.println(F("Commands:                                                                  "));
  Serial.println(F("datalog      Takes readings of all sensors every 15 sec send to thingspeak "));
  Serial.println(F("             Entering any commands stops datalog mode.                     "));
  Serial.println(F("poll         Takes readings continuously of all sensors                    "));
  Serial.println(F("                                                                           "));
  Serial.println(F("ph:cal,mid,7     calibrate to pH 7                                         "));
  Serial.println(F("ph:cal,low,4     calibrate to pH 4                                         "));
  Serial.println(F("ph:cal,high,10   calibrate to pH 10                                        "));
  Serial.println(F("ph:cal,clear     clear calibration                                         "));
  Serial.println(F("                                                                           "));
  Serial.println(F("ec:cal,dry           calibrate a dry EC probe                              "));
  Serial.println(F("ec:k,[n]             used to switch K values, standard probes values are 0.1, 1, and 10 "));
  Serial.println(F("ec:cal,clear         clear calibration                                     "));

  if(k_val > 9){
     Serial.println(F("For K10 probes, these are the recommended calibration values:            "));
     Serial.println(F("  ec:cal,low,12880     calibrate EC probe to 12,880us                    "));
     Serial.println(F("  ec:cal,high,150000   calibrate EC probe to 150,000us                   "));
  }
  else if(k_val > .9){
     Serial.println(F("For K1 probes, these are the recommended calibration values:             "));
     Serial.println(F("  ec:cal,low,12880     calibrate EC probe to 12,880us                    "));
     Serial.println(F("  ec:cal,high,80000    calibrate EC probe to 80,000us                    "));
  }
  else if(k_val > .09){
     Serial.println(F("For K0.1 probes, these are the recommended calibration values:           "));
     Serial.println(F("  ec:cal,low,84        calibrate EC probe to 84us                        "));
     Serial.println(F("  ec:cal,high,1413     calibrate EC probe to 1413us                      "));
  }
  
  Serial.println(F("                                                                           ")); 
  Serial.println(F("rtd:cal,t            calibrate the temp probe to any temp value            "));
  Serial.println(F("                     t= the temperature you have chosen                    "));
  Serial.println(F("rtd:cal,clear        clear calibration                                     "));
 }
```

Comment: Define "changed the I2C address"--the sensor board itself needs to have its I2C address changed--how exactly did you change its I2C address?

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for your question. I used an Arduino UNO and issued a command, "I2C, 50" in Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you update the code above to add your new sensor?

A quick look at Atlas' site and their Github page didn't find an obvious instruction to do what you're try to do, so that's the first thing I'd try if you haven't already. Below the Thinkspeak Credentials section, add your new device to the I2C devices definitions, then add its name to the array of available devices. I called the new temp sensor RTD2 in my example below, but you could probably call it something more descriptive of its function or placement. It looks like there is a name string in each definition that (I'm guessing) will be displayed in Thingspeak's data, and would be a good place to put a short description.

```cpp
        Ezo_board PH = Ezo_board(99, "PH");       //create a PH circuit object, who's address is 99 and name is "PH"
        Ezo_board EC = Ezo_board(100, "EC");      //create an EC circuit object who's address is 100 and name is "EC"
        Ezo_board RTD = Ezo_board(102, "RTD");    //create an RTD circuit object who's address is 102 and name is "RTD";
        Ezo_board RTD2 = Ezo_board(50, "RTD2");   //create an RTD circuit object who's address is 50 and name is "RTD2"
        Ezo_board PMP = Ezo_board(103, "PMP");    //create an PMP circuit object who's address is 103 and name is "PMP"
        
        Ezo_board device_list[] = {   //an array of boards used for sending commands to all or specific boards
          PH,
          EC,
          RTD,
          RTD2,
          PMP
        };
```

Update:

On review, it looks like you'll need to define an Arduino pin to enable the new device (in the `//enable pins for each circuit` section) and enable it at the head of `setup()` where the the other devices' pins are set to OUTPUT mode, and set this pin HIGH (guessing that your new RTD will be identical to your current one):

```cpp
//enable pins for each circuit
const int EN_PH = 14;
const int EN_EC = 12;
const int EN_RTD = 15;
const int EN_RTD2 =    <some available pin# here> ;
const int EN_AUX = 13;
```

And in setup():

```cpp
 pinMode(EN_RTD2, OUTPUT);

  ...

 digitalWrite(EN_RTD2, HIGH);
```

Update 2:

I think what we did above will get your new sensor data logged to Thingspeak, since I see a message referring to a "datalog mode" in `print_help()`. If you're expecting the control process to act your new sensor data in some way, you'll need to understand what it does now and what you want it to do differently based on the newly available data. But I would still take getting the system to just log the new data as your first step.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found a way to solve this problem following part of your answer. I edited my code only based on the first paragraph of your answer but not the rest of it. Rather, I edited void. step1 and void step 2.